# Found an interesting issue in Apex (compiling Illegal forward reference)

Tags: apex, bug

If we try to compile following code we get an error `Illegal forward reference: forwardVariable (2:40)`

```
public with sharing class A {
    public static String incorrectReference = forwardVariable;

    public static String forwardVariable = 'Hello World';
}
```

but if you reference `forwardVariable` through another class then it'll return null.

```
public with sharing class A {

    public static String incorrectReference = B.proxy;

    public static String forwardVariable = 'Hello World';
}

public with sharing class B {

    public static String proxy = A.forwardVariable;
}
```

```
System.debug(A.incorrectReference + ' ' + A.forwardVariable); // null Hello World
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forward references can only ever occur in the same method/class/code block. It means "referencing a variable that is declared later in the method." As such, one does need to be careful with circular references, and order of execution matters. For example, this code will behave properly:

```
public with sharing class A {
    public static String forwardVariable = 'Hello World';
    public static String incorrectReference = B.proxy;
}

public with sharing class B {
    public static String proxy = A.forwardVariable;
}
```

Because the forwardVariable was initialized in time, incorrectReference will have the correct value.

In general, this is why I advise against initializing inline, but instead initialize only in constructors and static blocks. This can help ensure that you understand the order of initialization.

By the way, this isn't a bug--it's expected behavior. Static variables are always initialized in source order. You can understand your original example as saying "A.incorrectReference needs to get B.proxy; B.proxy gets A.forwardVariable, which is null. Next, A.forwardReference is set to 'Hello World'". This is a perfectly logical conclusion if you walk through the steps manually.

Comment: Hey, Brian. Do you always use constructor initiation, because for me it's always looking like redundant code lines? I think that can also be solved by having non-dependant initializations first

Comment: @ytiq I don't generally "always" do anything, there's legitimate times when it's okay to break these self-imposed rules. For example, a "constants" class I typically use inline initializers, but never across class lines. Such classes must be self-contained. But for anything even remotely complicated, you bet I'm going to use a constructor or static block. It's not duplication of code, exactly, it's organization. The only downside is you can forget to initialize something, but these sorts of things usually present themselves early.

Comment: ok, cool. Thanks for an extended answer

Answer (score 1):

We can obviously prevent it by having a good code review and following best practices (i.e. avoiding circular dependencies between classes), but I guess it's still good to know that this thing can happen when someone is not accurate.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164004)

Comment: didn't think here will be an answer, my bad.

Comment: @ytiq When Brian's around, there's almost always an answer ;) That said, any chance you could find a way to format it in more of a QA style? It may get removed by the community otherwise despite being an interesting aspect to the language.

Comment: can someone link an example of good Q&A question, so I know how to fix it?

Comment: Or I'll just accept Brian's answer at the evening